# Bat to delete specific folders in subfolders listed in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

Bat to delete specific lis of subfolders

In windows xp I have a folder name `gaming` that contain 100 folders with names `games1`, `games2`, `games3` ... `games100`.

And inside every of those folders there is a huge list of **subfolders from 1 to 100000**.

And I have a **name list** of the 50000 **folders** that i want to delete
example of the name list that I want to remove without knowing the name of their parent directory

```
6383  
6385  
4850  
6395  
6396  
6397  
9865  
6401  
6408  
1200  
...  
..  
.
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "namelist=list.txt"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%namelist%") do set "$%%a=1"
for /d /r "gaming" %%a in (*) DO IF DEFINED $%%~na ECHO rd /s /q "%%~a"
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo` before `rd` if it looks good.

Comment: +1 This is the way I would do that! ;-) It is the fastest way to compare each file name vs. a long list of names...

Comment: ty for the answer, i copied the code inside a bat file and i run it but it didnot work , i want to mention that i need to delete 50000 folders not files

Comment: @Endoro Won't that only take the last name in list.txt and process that?

Comment: ty for the answer i didnt had time to test it but i had found other solution , i had found a way to get the name of each subfolders parents ty all for your help

Comment: @foxidrive I build an associative array `$foldername=1`. So comparing is extremely easy. Doesn't work with folder names that contains `=` .

Comment: @endoro Oops!  I must have been asleep. hehe

Answer (score 1):

This expects a `list.txt` in the `d:\folder\gaming` folder and it will create `"removefolders.bat.txt"` in the same folder.

Open that file in Notepad and verify that the correct folders are listed and then you can rename it to .bat and run it to actually delete the folders.

```
@echo OFF
pushd "d:\folder\gaming"
del "removefolders.bat.txt" 2>nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "list.txt" ') do (
for /d /r %%b in (*) do if "%%~nxb"=="%%a" >>"removefolders.bat.txt" echo rd /q /s "%%b"
)
popd
```

Comment: ty for your answer , i had found a solution for my problem